# Getting tags from python 3 dictionary object. AWS Boto3 Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

I have a dictionary object that is being returned to me from AWS. I need to pull the tag "based_on_ami" out of this dictionary. I have tried converting to a list, but I am new to programming and have not been able to figure out how to access Tags since they are a few levels down in the dictionary.

What is the best way for me to pull that tag out of the dictionary and put it into a variable i can use?

```js
{
   'Images':[
      {
         'Architecture':'x86_64',
         'CreationDate':'2017-11-27T14:41:30.000Z',
         'ImageId':'ami-8e73e0f4',
         'ImageLocation':'23452345234545/java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5',
         'ImageType':'machine',
         'Public':False,
         'OwnerId':'23452345234545',
         'State':'available',
         'BlockDeviceMappings':[
            {
               'DeviceName':'/dev/sda1',
               'Ebs':{
                  'Encrypted':False,
                  'DeleteOnTermination':True,
                  'SnapshotId':'snap-0c10e8f5ced5b5240',
                  'VolumeSize':8,
                  'VolumeType':'gp2'
               }
            },
            {
               'DeviceName':'/dev/sdb',
               'VirtualName':'ephemeral0'
            },
            {
               'DeviceName':'/dev/sdc',
               'VirtualName':'ephemeral1'
            }
         ],
         'EnaSupport':True,
         'Hypervisor':'xen',
         'Name':'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5',
         'RootDeviceName':'/dev/sda1',
         'RootDeviceType':'ebs',
         'SriovNetSupport':'simple',
         'Tags':[
            {
               'Key':'service',
               'Value':'baseami'
            },
            {
               'Key':'cloudservice',
               'Value':'ami'
            },
            {
               'Key':'Name',
               'Value':'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5'
            },
            {
               'Key':'os',
               'Value':'ubuntu 16.04 lts'
            },
            {
               'Key':'based_on_ami',
               'Value':'ami-aa2ea8d0'
            }
         ],
         'VirtualizationType':'hvm'
      }
   ],
   'ResponseMetadata':{
      'RequestId':'2c376c75-c31f-4aba-a058-173f3b125a00',
      'HTTPStatusCode':200,
      'HTTPHeaders':{
         'content-type':'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
         'transfer-encoding':'chunked',
         'vary':'Accept-Encoding',
         'date':'Fri, 01 Dec 2017 18:17:53 GMT',
         'server':'AmazonEC2'
      },
      'RetryAttempts':0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
info = {...}
tags = []
for image in info['Images']:
    for tag in image['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
            tags.append(tag['Value'])
print(tags)
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach this type of problem is to find the value you're looking for, and then work outwards until you find a solution. You need to look at what is at each of those levels.

So, what are you looking for? You're looking for the `Value` for `based_on_ami`'s `Key`. So your final step is going to be:

```
if obj['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
   # do something with obj['Value'].
```

But how do you get there? Well, the object is inside of a list, so you'll need to iterate the list:

```
for tag in <some list>:
   if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
       # do something with tag['Value'].
```

What is that list? It's the list of tags:

```
for tag in image['Tags']:
   if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
       # do something with tag['Value'].
```

And where are those tags? In an image object that you find in a list:

```
for image in image_list:
    for tag in image['Tags']:
       if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
           # do something with tag['Value'].
```

The image list is the value found at the `Images` key in your initial dict.

```
image_list = my_data['Images']
for image in image_list:
    for tag in image['Tags']:
       if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
           # do something with tag['Value'].
```

And now you're collecting all of those values, so you'll need a `list` and you'll need to append to it:

```
result = []
image_list = my_data['Images']
for image in image_list:
    for tag in image['Tags']:
       if tag['Key'] == 'based_on_ami':
           result.append(tag['Value'])
```

So, I took your example above, and added another `based_on_ami` node with the value `quack`:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '2c376c75-c31f-4aba-a058-173f3b125a00', 'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPHeaders': {'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Fri, 01 Dec 2017 18:17:53 GMT'}, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200}, 'Images': [{'Public': False, 'CreationDate': '2017-11-27T14:41:30.000Z', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'Ebs': {'SnapshotId': 'snap-0c10e8f5ced5b5240', 'VolumeSize': 8, 'Encrypted': False, 'VolumeType': 'gp2', 'DeleteOnTermination': True}, 'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1'}, {'VirtualName': 'ephemeral0', 'DeviceName': '/dev/sdb'}, {'VirtualName': 'ephemeral1', 'DeviceName': '/dev/sdc'}], 'OwnerId': '23452345234545', 'ImageLocation': '23452345234545/java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1', 'ImageType': 'machine', 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'State': 'available', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'Name': 'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'Tags': [{'Value': 'baseami', 'Key': 'service'}, {'Value': 'ami', 'Key': 'cloudservice'}, {'Value': 'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'Key': 'Name'}, {'Value': 'ubuntu 16.04 lts', 'Key': 'os'}, {'Value': 'ami-aa2ea8d0', 'Key': 'based_on_ami'}], 'EnaSupport': True, 'SriovNetSupport': 'simple', 'ImageId': 'ami-8e73e0f4'}, {'Public': False, 'CreationDate': '2017-11-27T14:41:30.000Z', 'BlockDeviceMappings': [{'Ebs': {'SnapshotId': 'snap-0c10e8f5ced5b5240', 'VolumeSize': 8, 'Encrypted': False, 'VolumeType': 'gp2', 'DeleteOnTermination': True}, 'DeviceName': '/dev/sda1'}, {'VirtualName': 'ephemeral0', 'DeviceName': '/dev/sdb'}, {'VirtualName': 'ephemeral1', 'DeviceName': '/dev/sdc'}], 'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', 'OwnerId': '23452345234545', 'ImageLocation': '23452345234545/java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1', 'ImageType': 'machine', 'Hypervisor': 'xen', 'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', 'State': 'available', 'Architecture': 'x86_64', 'Name': 'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'Tags': [{'Value': 'baseami', 'Key': 'service'}, {'Value': 'ami', 'Key': 'cloudservice'}, {'Value': 'java8server_ubuntu16-2b71edd1-f95e-4ee5-8fd6-d8a46975fdb5', 'Key': 'Name'}, {'Value': 'ubuntu 16.04 lts', 'Key': 'os'}, {'Value': 'quack', 'Key': 'based_on_ami'}], 'EnaSupport': True, 'SriovNetSupport': 'simple', 'ImageId': 'ami-8e73e0f4'}]}
```

My result:

```
['ami-aa2ea8d0', 'quack']
```